# What should I do to cover my gown pants?

Tags: rigging

[image]

I did rigging. When I raise legs, the gown digs into pants.

I also tried sending vertex point information to data transfer modifier, but it is useless.

There are tutorials that use simulations, but there are YouTubers who worked without using simulations, so I'm asking.

I planted a bone in the part that went inside and tried to protrude, but it didn't work.

my question is how to take out the part that goes in.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supermoon1234 is correct, putting the armature first and subdivision surface second helps a lot already. In between these two modifiers you can also add a **corrective smooth** modifier. This applies smoothing after a deformation that approaches the original form before the deformation. You can also set a vertex group for this, to control what areas need smoothing and which don't. Adding a subdivision surface to the legs and disabling 'Use Limit Surface' will help too.
[image]
For this I reduced some of the smoothing around the bum, because it started to poke through. I also added a corrective smooth modifier and subdivision surface to the legs.

A warning I should give is that if this is a model for a game, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to make use of corrective smooth. In that case you'll have to rely on your rig and good weight painting.

Comment: I use this for youtube 3d animation. Butt sticking out can be solved with a poke face. It help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Modifire's order has been changed, and it's been resolved to some extent.